# Is there any advantage in using atomic_init over atomic_store ?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, shared-memory, multicore

I read the cpp documentation and understood that

**Atomic_init**
       -is non atomic and prone to data race(so it carries a problem)
       -from the term 'init' in the instruction, i believe that it must be                   used to initialize the variable for the first time.

**Atomic_store**
  -stores a value atomically into the atomic variable

So why don't we use atomic store to initialize the variable? If so why do they have the atomic_init?

Is there any advantage in using atomic_init over atomic_store ?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you shouldn't need to  atomically initialize anything, because that would imply that multiple threads are competing to utilize uninitialized memory.

Generally, the memory is single-threaded during construction/initialization, but then, it is "published" in such a way that other threads can begin using it.

In the case of global atomics, generally you would initialize these early, before more threads even exist yet.

The advantages of using `Atomic_init`  would be to explicitly denote an initialization, and to bypass a small amount of overhead.

Comment: how would one "publish" the fact the the atomic is initialized?